# Showing a characterisation of curves with constant slope.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

**Here is what I would like to prove:**

Let $\alpha:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a curve. Assume $\alpha\in C^3$ and that $\dot\alpha(t)$ and $\ddot\alpha(t)$ are linearly independent $\forall t\in I$. Then:

$\alpha$ is a curve with constant slope $\iff \vec{T}(\alpha,t)$ makes a constant angle with the Darboux vector.

**Notation:**

$\tau=\frac{\langle \vec{B},\vec{N} \rangle}{\|\dot\alpha(t)\|}$ is the torsion.

$\kappa=\|\vec{K}\|=\|\frac{\dot{T}}{\|\dot\alpha(t)\|}\|$ is the curvature.

The Darboux vector is : $\vec{D}(\alpha,t)=\tau(\alpha,t)\vec{T}(\alpha,t)+\kappa(\alpha,t)\vec{B}(\alpha,t)$

$\vec{T}$ is the tangent vector (i.e. $\vec{T}(\alpha,t)=\frac{\dot\alpha(t)}{\|\dot\alpha(t)\|}$), $\vec{N}$ the normal vector and $\vec{B}$ is the binormal vector (all three from the Frenet–Serret frame).

**What I know:**

I know that a curve has a constant slope if and only if the ratio between the torsion and the curvature is constant, i.e. $\frac{\tau}{\kappa}$ is constant.

For the $\implies$ part of the proof I wanted to write :

$$\cos(\angle(\vec{T},\vec{D}))=\frac{\langle\vec{T},\vec{D}\rangle}{\|\vec{T}\|\|\vec{D}\|}=\frac{\langle\vec{T},\tau\vec{T}+\kappa\vec{B}\rangle}{\|\vec{T}\|\|\tau\vec{T}+\kappa\vec{B}\|}$$

to show that the angle is constant but I can't get anywhere. As for the other part of the proof ($\Longleftarrow$) I do not know where to begin.

Any hint or help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of showing this is constant would be to differentiate the cosine expression, and to show that the derivative vanishes.  Here presumably one would have to use the Frenet-Serret formulas.  I would be surprised if this doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't found the time to do this properly today but I will definitely try to do it tomorrow. I just fear that it will be a big mess…

Answer (score 0):

Although @user72694 suggests a tried and true method for differential geometry problems, here it is overkill.

Note that if $\tau=c\kappa$, then the Darboux vector is parallel to $c\vec T+\vec B$, which in turn has constant length.

For the converse, just use high school algebra with your formula and solve for $\tau/\kappa$.